# Prevent sorted list losing sort order after JSON.serialization

Tags: apex, visualforce, json

I have a controller method which returns a list to VF page in a sorted order. After sorting I am serializing the list to send to VF. However JSON.serialization which destroys the order of the list. Now how to maintain the order of the list after serialization.  Thanks in advance.

```
List<ApprovalsListData> approvalWrapperListNew = new List<ApprovalsListData>();
approvalWrapperListNew.add( approvalWrapperList[0]); 
ApprovalsListData temp; 
for (integer i = 0; i < approvalWrapperList.size(); i++) 
{ 
    // sorts here
}
return JSON.serialize(approvalWrapperList);
```

Comment: Are you working with a regular Apex List or a Map?

Comment: regular apex list

Comment: Can you share a code snippet?

Comment: List<ApprovalsListData> approvalWrapperListNew = new  List<ApprovalsListData>();
            approvalWrapperListNew.add( approvalWrapperList[0]);
            ApprovalsListData temp;
            for (integer i = 0; i < approvalWrapperList.size(); i++)
            {
               sorts here///
            }
   return JSON.serialize(approvalWrapperList);

Comment: The code sample does not seem to make much sense to me I'm afraid. I'll write a more generic sample and check this out, my gut feel is it should retain it, I'll seek to confirm or not the case for you.

Answer (score 5):

I can confirm the List's are serialised and deserialised in consistent order, this example outputs this to debug log...

> {
>
> "stringData" : "One",
>
> "index" : 1
>
> }, {
>
> "stringData" : "Two",
>
> "index" : 2
>
> }, {
>
> "stringData" : "Three",
>
> "index" : 3
>
> } ]

Are you sure whatever is deserilising the JSON is not putting it in a map of some kind perhaps? JavaScript client?

```
@IsTest
private static void testTheOrderOfThings()
{
    // Build a list with items in a specific order
    List<ListDataItem> dataList = new List<ListDataItem>();
    ListDataItem item1 = new ListDataItem();
    item1.index = 1;
    item1.stringData = 'One';
    dataList.add(item1);
    ListDataItem item2 = new ListDataItem();
    item2.index = 2;
    item2.stringData = 'Two';
    dataList.add(item2);
    ListDataItem item3 = new ListDataItem();
    item3.index = 3;
    item3.stringData = 'Three';
    dataList.add(item3);

    // Serialise the list and dump the JSON to the debug log
    String jsonData = JSON.serializePretty(dataList);
    System.debug(jsonData);

    // Deserialise it to the list and check the order is still as expected
    dataList = (List<ListDataItem>) 
        JSON.deserialize(
            jsonData, 
                List<ListDataItem>.class);      
    System.assertEquals(1, dataList[0].index); 
    System.assertEquals('One', dataList[0].stringData); 
    System.assertEquals(2, dataList[1].index); 
    System.assertEquals('Two', dataList[1].stringData); 
    System.assertEquals(3, dataList[2].index); 
    System.assertEquals('Three', dataList[2].stringData); 
}
public class ListDataItem
{
    public Integer index;
    public String stringData;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Fawcett. The issue was not with  salesforce  JSON serialisation rather it was ui issue. Thanks for your reply

Comment: You welcome, glad i was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

For your sorting, have you tried using a `comparable interface`?  I only started using it a couple weeks ago, and it's pretty slick.

[Salesforce Docs on Comparable Interfaces](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_comparable.htm)

(don't mind setting your classes to `Global`.  `Public` is fine.)

**Example:**

```
public class Cntrlr_TestPage{

    public class myWrapperClass implements Comparable{
        public boolean selected {get;set;}
        public MyCustomObject__c record {get;set;}

        // constructors
        public myWrapperClass(){
            this.selected=false;
            this.record=new MyCustomOjbect__c();
        }//END init()

        public myWrapperClass(MyCustomOjbect__c record){    // the constructor you'll usually use
            this.selected=false;
            this.record=record;
        }//END init()

        public myWrapperClass(boolean selected, MyCustomOjbect__c record){   // for JSON serialization
            this.selected=selected;
            this.record=record;
        }//END init()

        // the required method compareTo(object comp)
        public integer compareTo(object comp){
            myWrapperClass compObj=(myWrapperClass)comp;
            // compare against this instance 
            // return -1 if THIS < COMP
            // return 0 if THIS == COMP
            // return 1 if THIS > COMP
        }//END compareTo(object comp)
    }//END myWrapperClass


    list<myWrapperClass> myList;

    // constructors ( •_•)   ( •_•)>⌐■-■   (⌐■_■)

    public string getMyListAsJSON(){
        myList.sort();     // <----------------------- SORT the list
        return JSON.serialize(myList);  //<----- should do the trick.

        //           ▇ ▅ █ ▅ ▇ ▂ ▃ ▁ ▁ ▅ ▃ ▅ ▅ ▄ ▅ ▇
        // (for your problem) Are you sure you're giving JSON.serialize the sorted list?
        //  can you spot the rhyme or reason to JSON.serialize ignoring your sort?  
        //  I use sorting + JSON.serialize to track user's history as they navigate some of my Sites, and the code works fine.
        //           ▇ ▅ █ ▅ ▇ ▂ ▃ ▁ ▁ ▅ ▃ ▅ ▅ ▄ ▅ ▇
    }//END getMyList()


}//END Cntrlr_TestPage
```

Comment: Thanks amatorVitae I am using comparable interface. The issue was not salesforce  JSON serialisation rather it was ui issue